# Can "short of" be used with a specific amount (cash)?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, phrase-usage, usage

In another [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/161529/48962) regarding a difference between **short on** and **short of,** the [answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/161530/48962) says the following:

> ... But this is not always the case. A person can be short on/of money,
>   but lacking a specific amount, someone can only be €10 short or short
>   €10. This construction never uses a preposition.

but is that really true? I can see sentences like "I am short of 10 dollars" quite often.

Comment: Can you cite some specific examples of uses like "I am short of 10 dollars"? It sounds really wrong to my ear. (But "I am **[some amount] short of** 10 dollars" and "I am **10 dollars short of** [the amount I need]" and also "I am short **by** 10 dollars" are OK, so exact context would help.)

Comment: @1006a So basically the answer there is incorrect? I am confused, so many posters there confirmed it is correct :( https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/170246/can-i-be-a-few-players-short/170247#170247

Comment: 'shorty by' instead of 'short on' sounds more natural and likely to be used.

Answer (score 16):

When the meaning is "to have an amount that is less, by some amount, than a required amount" it is idiomatic not to use **of** but to say

> I'm short ten dollars. I need to visit the ATM.

**short** + shortage-amount

You need ten  dollars more in order to reach the amount needed.

When the meaning is "not reaching a number, less than" then you find **of**:

> The population of the district is short of 10,000.
>
> The tallest building in that city was short of 100 storeys.

The population might be 9,873 and the building could be, say, 97 storeys high. The implication is that the number is approaching the specified number.

Comment: *I am short of ten dollars* would mean "I have somewhat less than ten dollars".  *I am short ten dollars* would mean "I need ten dollars more".

Comment: Are you sure? https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/170246/can-i-be-a-few-players-short/170247#170247

Comment: That is what I do not get - so I can say "The team is short of a few players" or "The team is short of 2 players" and it does mean that we lack a few or two. But with money it does not work?

Comment: To my ear *We are short of a few players* (where **short of** means "missing"  or "lacking") is non-standard, but I do concede that I've heard the phrase used.  The problem is that in any language there will always be a fraction of the population that uses words, phrases, tenses, etc in a way that differs to some degree from the way the rest of the speaking population  use them.

Comment: It works with money. The bill is $100. I have $98. I am short of (or by) $2, or I am short $2.

Comment: I would regard *I am short of $2* as non-standard when the meaning is "I need $2 more". And by "non-standard" all I mean is that a relatively small fraction of the population would say it that way.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo But this usage "short"+amount is not mentioned in Oxford dictionary, or at least I did not find it there. In addition, with "short of" in all the examples there, there is always amount mentioned in front of "short of"  - like "the building is a few stories short of 100".

Comment: In the US, I would interpret "We are short of a few players" to mean "we don't even have a few players", not "we only need a few players to complete the team": "short of X" means "not reaching X".

Comment: @1006a And if you add "to"? As in: We are short a few players to start the match.

Comment: @user970696 That sounds fine, because you've omitted the "of", which is the crux of the issue ("short of X" has a different meaning than "short X").

Comment: "Short of" can also be used in a quantitative but non-numerical context. For example, "Any measure short of a constitutional amendment could be circumvented or ignored..." ([source](https://www.ctwoodlands.org/public-policy/constitutional-amendment-protect-your-public-lands-necessary-now)) I think this is actually the most common use of "short of."

Comment: @user970696: The answer on [Can I be "a few players short"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/170247) you cited is incorrect, IMO; it's not idiomatic to say "The team is short of a few players".  I left a comment on that answer: "short *by* 2 players" could work to measure the size of the shortfall.  (@Tᴚoɯɐuo says they've heard it, so if it is used in some parts of the world then it's probably specific to that context (sports teams or groups of people), not standard grammar.)

Comment: If you're lacking two players to start a game, you can say "we're two players short" or "we're short two players" or even "we're short *by* two players". However, "we're short of two players" is wrong. Same goes for money if you are lacking $2 to buy something. If you list a specific amount, ommit the "of". The phrase "short of" is vague and means "almost there" just like the examples in the answer show.

Comment: @AlexandreAubrey Are from US? Because from what I was told, US do not use the preposition, while BrE does, which is why answers differ.

Comment: @user970696 People use prepositions regardless of where they're from, but not all prepositions bring the same meaning to the sentence. If you want to use a preposition between "we're short" and "two players" you could use either *"by"* or *"of"*. In these cases *"by"* would indicate you need two more players, *"of"* means you have less than two players. As far as I know this is pretty universal.

Comment: @user970696 typing "short of" into google gives results "less than, not reaching as far as, without going so far as (some extreme action)". So, replacing "short of" with "less than", "short of $5" means "less than $5", synonymous to "don't even have $5". I did a bit more reading, and I found that being short of (object) i.e "I'm short of cash/developers/players" seems to be accepted as lacking the required amount of cash/developers/players (I was wrong and it's just my regional use that throws me off and makes it seem weird) but still means "less than" for specific amounts i.e "short of $5"

Answer (score 4):

One very often sees and hears expressions like I am short **of** [a sum of money], meaning I lack that sum which I have an immediate need for, or I need that sum to reach some needed total amount, e.g. a bill. To say "This construction never uses a preposition" is sweeping and misleading.

There is a specific usage, common in British English, that may or may not be widespread, I don't know. It is this: we can use 'short' or 'short by' to discuss a shortfall discovered when checking accounts. For example, a manager might check a shop worker's till and say "your till is short [by] six pounds", meaning the sum found in the till is £6 less than it should be.

Comment: It is common in American English as well.