# “ send something a few amount short”

Tags: meaning

> My supplier sent  my raw material 250 kg short of the full amount .

Is use of '' short '' correct in this sentence ? Can I use this in this way? What I want to say is that My order which was raw material was sent by my supplier. But it was 250 kg less than total amount.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can "short of" be used with a specific amount (cash)?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/170408/can-short-of-be-used-with-a-specific-amount-cash)

Answer (score 0):

Yes its fine, and idiomatic. You might have heard the expression "a few eggs short of a dozen" to refer to someone who is a little slow on the uptake.